# How to write htaccess rewrite rule for seo friendly url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

- I am just new to `.htaccess`.
- I need some rewrite rules for `URLs`.
- I Google'd some and applied but no change in URL.

I want:

```
demo.example.com/section.php?id=1
```

Changed to:

```
demo.example.com/section/sample-section
```

i tried

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^section/(\d+)*$ ./section.php?id=$1
```

but no difference

Thanks.

I will appreciate your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Comment: Could you paste your full `.htaccess`? Is the rewrite module installed and enabled?

Comment: Links are usually discouraged on SO that's why I am putting this in a comment. A must read for every mod_rewrite beginner. http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-in-depth-guide-to-mod_rewrite-for-apache--net-6708

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, make sure *mod_rewrite* is **enabled** and htaccess files **allowed** in your Apache configuration.

Then, put this code in your htaccess (which has to be in root folder)

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# redirect "/section.php?id=xxx" to "/section/xxx"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/section\.php\?id=([0-9]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /section/%1? [R=301,L]

# internally rewrite "/section/xxx" to "/section.php?id=xxx"
RewriteRule ^section/([0-9]+)$ /section.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: lurman thank you . it works very fine. one thing i want to ask.
Now i have to change my php code accordingly . i mean have to explude and get section title ?

Comment: Well actually you don't have to change anything since you still get `id` parameter "in the back" (hidden). I'm not sure i understood your question, if that's not the case, please explain

Comment: yeas this is what i wanted to know about id .

But after apply this htaccess . am getting 404 error.

Comment: What is exactly the url you tried ? Also, make sure *mod_rewrite* is enabled and *htaccess* allowed in your apache configuration

Comment: http://temp.example.com/section.php?id=6
is now 
http://temp.example.com/section/6

Comment: Yes, isn't it what you wanted ?

Comment: yes exactly . but is it normal, that i am getting 404 error now ?

Comment: Since first rule is working correctly, second should too. So, no, this is not normal. Do you have other rules in your htaccess ?

Comment: No i have nothing else in htaccess

Comment: I just read your update. That's because you don't use my second rule (the last line in my code is mandatory too)

Comment: I am using both now . but still getting 404

Comment: Definetely weird. Do you have access to error logs ?

Comment: Yes and that is clean. no error. . . actually am working in a subdomain. . does it has to effect anything ?

Comment: It could. What is the root folder of your subdomain ? Is it the same as main domain ?

Comment: What if you replace last line by this one: `RewriteRule ^section/([0-9]+)$ /temp/section.php?id=$1 [L]`

Comment: Thank Justin. . no need to change anything.  i just moved my code to root and its working fine. . thanks

Comment: That's what i said in my answer (`which has to be in root folder`). That's why second rule wasn't working. Glad your problem is solved, you're welcome !

Comment: Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On

    # redirect "/section.php?id=xxx" to "/section/xxx"
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/section\.php\?id=([0-9]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^temp/section/%1? [R=301,L]

    # internally rewrite "/section/xxx" to "/section.php?id=xxx"
    RewriteRule ^temp/section/([0-9]+)$ /section.php?id=$1 [L] 

this works for subdomain too now 

thanks again :)

Comment: is it possible to change 6 to example-title in url 
like example.com/section/6  to example.com/section/travel 

id=6 has a title name travel in database

Comment: Sure but you should post another question instead, since it would be a bit different from your initial question here

Comment: thank u justin . can you please help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28171065/hot-replace-id-with-associated-db-title-in-url-using-htaccess

Comment: @JustinIurman Can you help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30242996/url-rewriting-and-url-redirection

Answer (score 6):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^section/([^/]+)$ /section.php?id=$1 [L]
```

This will turn `example.com/section.php?id=X` to `example.com/section/X`

I suggest storing the URI in a database then using section.php?uri=

For example:

`example.com/section.php?uri=super-awesome`

would turn into:

`example.com/section/super-awesome`