# URL rewriting and redirection (with database data)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My url is `http://testurl.com/user.php?id=1&name=TestUser`

My default url for above link would need to be like `http://testurl.com/user/12345/TestUser`

If user try to change it in own browser link like below

```
http://testurl.com/user/12345
http://testurl.com/user/12345/
http://testurl.com/user/12345/TestUsers_bla-bla
```

then url bar automatically changes to `http://testurl.com/user/12345/TestUser`

**Edit**

```
<?php
$name = "This-is-a-test-user";
$id = 1;


$fields = array('id' => $id,
                'name' => $name);


$url = "http://localhost/view_user.php?" . http_build_query($fields, '', "&");
?>

<a href = "<?php echo $url; ?>"> View User</a>
```

Comment: What do you have in your htaccess file so far? Have you tried any rewrite rules?

Comment: At the moment its blank. I tried multiple options but none of them are working. So, after each failure i start from the scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two things here.

**1)** htaccess rules to handle

- `http://testurl.com/user/12345`
- `http://testurl.com/user/12345/`
- `http://testurl.com/user/12345/xxx`

**and** corresponding rules to avoid duplicate content (redirect old format `/user.php?xxx` to new format `/user/ID/NAME`)

To do so, you can put this code in your root htaccess

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/user\.php\?id=([0-9]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ user/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/user\.php\?id=([0-9]+)&name=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ user/%1/%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^user/([0-9]+)/?$ user.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^user/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)$ user.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L]
```

Note: at this point, make sure *mod_rewrite* is enabled and `htaccess` allowed (in Apache configuration file).

A simple test: `http://example.com/user/12345/XXXXX` should internally rewrite to `/user.php?id=12345&name=XXXXX`.

**2)** Now you need to adapt `user.php` logic (this is here you check for your data `<ID, NAME>` pair existence)

```
<?php
if (!isset($_GET['id']) || empty($_GET['id']))
{
   // error page not found (since there is no ID)
   header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
   return;
}

if (!isset($_GET['name']) || empty($_GET['name']))
{
   // no name -> get it by its ID
   $name = getNameByID($_GET['id']); // this function checks in the database

   if ($name === NULL)
   {
      // error: ID is unknown -> page not found
      header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
      return;
   }

   // ID exists, we now have its name -> redirect to /user/ID/NAME (instead of /user/ID)
   header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
   header("Location: /user/".$_GET['id']."/".$name);
   return;
}

// if we reach here, we have an ID and a name in the url
// we have to check if NAME corresponds to ID (and if ID exists)

$name = getNameByID($_GET['id']); // this function checks in the database

if ($name === NULL)
{
   // error: ID is unknown -> page not found
   header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
   return;
}

// now, check if NAME in the url corresponds to the one we got from database

if ($name !== $_GET['name'])
{
   // it doesn't -> redirect to good NAME
   header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
   header("Location: /user/".$_GET['id']."/".$name);
   return;
}

// finally, here we're fine.
// do what you then have to do...

?>
```

I intentionally write this code with "duplicate" parts to let you understand the logic.
Of course, you can improve it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and explanation. I will give it try tonight and let you know.

Comment: Does above code will create pretty url too? Actually i have a page that have this link http://testurl.com/user.php?id=1&name=TestUser. this link still showing as it is. I have added the entry in .htaccess file but i am getting same link on the page and on the browser address bar. Is there anyway i can troubleshoot.

Comment: Htaccess rules are there to make sure the url displayed is the new format (pretty url). But It doesn't mean you can't have something wrong, such as `http://example.com/user/12345/NAME_OF_ID_45678` (or even "worst", an unknown ID). That's why i added a php logic code to handle it. Also, make sure you have enabled *mod_rewrite* and htaccess are allowed (all in Apache config file). Note: your htaccess must be in root folder

Comment: one more thing i want to know. <a href = "http://testurl.com/user.php?id=1&name=TestUser"> View User</a> when i place mouse on this link. Will it display http://testurl.com/user.php?id=1&name=TestUser this or http://testurl.com/user/1/TestUser

Comment: You're encouraged to replace your "old" links by "new" links (pretty url) but that's not mandatory since htaccess will redirect old format to new format. If you try it (click on your old link), you'll get a redirect to `http://testurl.com/user/1/TestUser`

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. One more question is in stackoverflow links we can see link like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30242996/url-rewriting-and-redirection-with-database-data. I know about slug and i know how to create slug. why SO link look like this?

Comment: Well SO links are exactly what my answer does. It's based on the ID. As an example, you can try to change the ID part only, or the question-title-part only, and you'll see how it's handled (as my php logic). It's mandatory since htaccess doesn't know anything about data from database. Finally, SO made its links look like this for SEO reason: it's more user friendly than (for instance) `/questions.aspx?ID=30242996` and you have the benefit of having question-title in url. That's also (at least, it was, it's not mandatory anymore) better for referencing

Comment: @justinlurman  could please have a look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30280098/url-rewriteslug-and-url-redirection-htaccess

Comment: @justinlurman http://testurl.com/user/12345/ this is not working properly. I am getting 404. I tried multiple times but no luck. any advise.

Comment: It's hard to say considering the fact that it has changed a lot since your initial question (there's also another question you posted after). The better would be to post a brand new question with your current code

Comment: Thanks Justin. I will post new question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in root/.htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^user/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ /user.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^user/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ /user.php?id=$1&name=$2 [QSA,L]
```

The conditions make sure you don't rewrite any existing file/directories on the server.

Comment: If possible could you please elaborate it. As i want to understand don't want to just copy n paste the code. Thanks

Comment: Your welcome! Apache documentation has a basic tutorial on Mod_rewrite. please have a look ..  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 1):

Why not try to get a very basic rule working, then go from there.

First you need to make sure you server has the rewrite module enabled, then at the top of your htaccess file put:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Then you can put your re-write rules using regex. Eg:

```
 RewriteRule ^user/(\w+)/(\w+)$ user.php?id=$1&name=$2
```