# URL rewrite(SLUG) and URL redirection (htaccess)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Below is my php code(qs.php). This file contain url links. Pretty links created by using SLUG.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <?php
    function create_slug($string){
       $slug=preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9-]+/', '-', $string);
       $slug = strtolower($slug);
       return $slug;
    }
    $slugurl=  create_slug('SLUG-text-testing-purpose-only');

    $file = 'qs1'; //this is a php file qs1.php
    $id = '12345678'; //testing ID
    $complete_url = $file."/".$id."/".$slugurl;

    ?>
    <a href ="<?php echo $full;?>"> This is a test link created by slug</a>

</body></html>
```

Above link appear like this - `http://localhost/qs/qs1/12345678/slug-text-testing-purpose-only`

**Edit**

QS is a directory where all files are placed. QS1 is a php file (qs1.php)

I want to get two variable from above link `12345678 & slug-text-testing-purpose-only`. 
as qs1.php is file where i get these two variables from `$_GET['var1'] & $_GET['var2'];`

I know it can be achieved by `.htaccess`. i tried multiple options but they are not working as i am getting 404.

.htaccess file is placed on QS directory.

Below are the options i had tried.

```
RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^qs/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)$ qs1.php?var1=$1&var2=$2 [L]

    RewriteRule ^/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /qs1.php?var1=$1&var2=$2 [L]

    RewriteRule  ^qs/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /qs1.php?var1=$1&var2=$2  [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule /qs/(\d+)/(.*) qs1.php?id=$1&slug=$2    [QSA,L]
```

I am very new to htaccess and url redirect.

Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: Is qs1/ a directory?

Comment: no, its a php file qs1.php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put this code in `/qs/.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /qs/

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(\d+)/([^/]+)$ $1.php?var1=$2&var2=$3 [NC,L]
```

Now, you can go to `http://localhost/qs/qs1/12345678/slug-text-testing-purpose-only` and you'll get the same content as `/qs/qs1.php?var1=12345678&var2=slug-text-testing-purpose-only`

Comment: I tried the above code but issue still the same. Just for curiosity $1.php is this correct in above rule. i didn't understand it.

Comment: Could you be more specific ? What does not work ? What do you get ?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, i didn't see `qs1.php` (and others) were in `/qs/` folder. You can try with my edited code (**don't forget:** htaccess in `/qs/` folder)

Comment: http://localhost/qs1.php?var1=12345678&var2=slug-text-testing-purpose-only  this doesn't work as qs1.php & htaccess files are under qs directory.

Comment: @justinlurman Page is redirecting but inside the page css & js files are not  loading properly. When i check firebug i found this "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/qs/qs1/12345678/css/main.css". Code in qs1.php is <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">. Any suggestion on this.

Comment: This is a normal behaviour since you're using relative paths for your html resources. Considering your css (and others) are in root folder, you can add a leading slash for all your resources (e.g. `href="/css/main.css"` or, instead of replacing each links, you can add this tag after `<head>` : `<base href="/">`.

Comment: Agreed but in my case they are under two sub directories. So, if i use base or absolute path. Issue persists. Any advise.

Comment: Well that's the same logic. All you have to do is to include subfolders in the path. For instance: `/subfolder1/subfolder2/css/main.css` (or with base tag: `<base href="/subfolder1/subfolder2/">`)

Comment: @justinlurman Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30325086/apache-url-rewrite-redirection-with-database-data

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^qs/qs1/(\d+)/(.+)$    qs1.php?var1=$1&var2=$2    [NC,L]
```

You can play with it here: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be

Comment: There is a chance your mode_rewrite is not enabled or server ignores .htaccess. Apache?

Comment: For Apache, be sure you have `AllowOverride All` for the *Directory* + run `a2enmod rewrite`

Comment: Its enabled i tried to put garbage value in htaccess file and it is giving me 500 error. Anyways, i have a WAMP server. Please let me know how can i enable htaccess.

Comment: Well, if it shows 500 when you make changes in the *htaccess* file, then you already have this `AllowOverride All`. Can you show your entire .htaccess?

Comment: Its in question. I placed that. Nothing else in htaccess file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77983/discussion-between-axalix-and-user2301394).