# Apache URL rewrite/redirection with database data

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Here is my php code(qs.php). This file contain pretty url links.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <?php  
    $file = 'qs1'; //this is a php file qs1.php
    $id = '12345678'; //testing ID
    $complete_url = $file."/".$id;

    ?>
    <a href ="<?php echo $complete_url;?>"> This is a test link </a>

</body></html>
```

This link appear link this - `http://localhost/qs1/12345678`

QS1 is a php file (qs1.php).

Below is the htaccess file so far.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(\d+)/([^/]+)$ $qs1.php?var1=$2 [NC,L]
```

In qs1.php file i am getting query string `var1` by `$_GET['var1']`

I want link can be accessible by this url `http://localhost/qs1/12345678`.
and if user put slash at the end like this `http://localhost/qs1/12345678/` then page redirect itself to this `http://localhost/qs1/12345678`.

At the moment i am getting error 404 while opening this `http://localhost/qs1/12345678/`

Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your rule does not match since it waits for something else after digits
e.g. `http://example.com/qs1/12345678/something`

You can use this code in your htaccess

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# we don't touch existing files/folders
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# remove trailing slash (for instance: redirect /qs1/12345678/ to /qs1/12345678)
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(\d+)/$ $1/$2 [R=301,L]

# rewrite /xxx/12345 to /xxx.php?var1=12345 (if xxx.php exists)
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(\d+)$ $1.php?var1=$2 [L]

# rewrite /xxx/12345/something to /xxx.php?var1=12345&var2=something (if xxx.php exists)
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(\d+)/([^/]+)$ $1.php?var1=$2&var2=$3 [L]
```

Comment: @justinlurman it doesn't look good to bother you all d time. I have asked a question and no one replied yet. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30416595/hyperlinks-not-working-redirection-while-using-pretty-url-with-htaccess