# htaccess to rewrite uri into get if not file/folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need htaccess rule that rewrites an uri into get variable if it is not for an existing file or folder.
Example:

```
www.example.com/page1.php -> goto page1.php
www.example.com/page2.html -> goto page2.html
www.example.com/folder -> goto /folder
www.example.com/some_string_value -> rewrite as /default.php?value=some_string_value
```

Comment: You might have to handle this in the code and redirect as appropriate. Htaccess won't know if this is a 404 or 200. It just routes it as you want it to.

Comment: I apologize if I come across as rude or elitist, but this is not a request forum. You need to show the community you have made an attempt to research and that you are posting because you were unable to understand/comprehend what is going on. Simply saying "I need x" will not work around here. Sorry.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write htaccess rewrite rule for seo friendly url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28168375/how-to-write-htaccess-rewrite-rule-for-seo-friendly-url)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's really a very common request. There are probably 1000's of questions about this asked on this site. You need to use the `RewriteCond` and `REQUEST_FILENAME` to look for non existent folder and then internally rewrite to get variable. Essentially if it's a `404 (non existent URI)` it will be routed to  your default.php file. That's how pretty URL's are done. You can put this in your .htaccess file in the root.

```
RewriteEngine On
#prevent the use of the default.php file directly and redirect to friendly URI
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} [A-Z]{3,9}\ /default\.php\?value=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]
#redirect non existent (404) folder to get variable
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /default.php?value=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I find it frustrating that well thought questions are ignored, yet requests for code are fulfilled on this site. It should be flagged as a duplicate and moved on, however the quality of your answer still deserves an upvote. I just wanted to make it clear the frustration of the patterns of answering occuring here lately.

Comment: @Tarquin thanks and you do have a point and that's why I at least try to provide a little insight into what he needed instead of just giving the code. There should have been some effort shown. I've been there once so just trying to help others. :)

Comment: I fully understand. I too want to give back to SO as it has been kind to me for years too.

Comment: @Tarquin I am  sorry if my way of questioning bothered you. I am fairly new at putting questions in this site but one thing is for sure that this site has helped me a lot in past and I assure you that I would keep your suggestions into consideration while posting questions in near future.