# htaccess cant get rewrite seo friendly url

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

hi i have use many different htaccess codes, but i cant get rewrite to work.
i want this url
    https://domain.com/category.php?cat=firm
to look like this url
    https://domain.com/category/firm

this is my latest attempt

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /category.php?cat=$1 [L]
ErrorDocument 404 https://seoboost.no/404page.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.seoboost\.no$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/seoboost\.no\/" [R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/example\.com\/" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.*
RewriteRule .* ? [F]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.php$ /$1/ [R=301]
```

i have try to delete all in my htaccess and only have this code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /category.php?cat=$1 [L]
```

but it still not working, is my server or what am i doing wrong??

Comment: Not working **HOW**?

Comment: it doesnt rewrite the url, removing the .php?cat=

Comment: you have to output the clean url. the only thing the client should EVER see is clean urls. rewriting to "ugly" urls should be an internal server thing only. e.g. if the client has this in the html `<a href="/category.php?cat=kittens">`, then no amount of server-side rewriting can change that.

Comment: how should i then send the variable to the dynamic php page??

Comment: `/category/1` should be the ONLY thing that ever shows up in the browser, then your rewrites translate `/category/1 -> category.php?id=1`. The client should NEVER see `category.php?id=1`,b ecause that's an internal-only url.

Comment: if i send this url /category/firm how should i do that in my htaccess??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing your .htaccess with

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)$ /category.php?cat=$1 [L]
```

which will redirect `yoursite.com/category/12` to `yoursite.com/category.php?cat=12` internally, and the user will never see the "ugly" url. Then inside your category.php file you can access the cat by `$category_id = $_GET['cat']`

A simple anchor tag looks like this:

```
<a href="https://yoursite.com/category/12">Item 12</a>
```

Comment: thx i got to work with this rule and links like category/firm

Comment: Glad it worked, you can add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` between `RewriteEngine On` and `RewriteRule ...` if you want to make sure the requested url is not a folder, nor a file.

Answer (score 0):

Pulling from [Justin Lurman's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28169103/2694511), the following should work:

```
RewriteEngine On

# redirect "/category.php?cat=..." to "/category/..." to hide a directly accessed "ugly" url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/category\.php\?cat=(.+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /category/%1? [R=301,L]

# internally rewrite "/category/..." to "/category.php?cat=..."
RewriteRule ^category/(.+)$ /category.php?id=$1 [L]
```

As Justin noted in that answer to a similar question, you need to confirm that htaccess files are enabled/allowed in your Apache configuration and that `mod_rewrite` is enabled.

Additionally, I am sure you are aware, but just in case you are not, after implementing this new htaccess redirect rule, you should change all of the links on your webpages to use clean/friendly URLs. By doing so, neither your users nor a search engine crawler will access the "ugly" URLs unless they access them directly (via a bookmark or a saved link).

Comment: it did rewrite the url but i couldnt get it to work with my variables. i dont know why but the internal rewrite didnt work??