# Rewrite query string special characters to url?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want my PHP file to pass: `mysite.com/?id=ABC123abc` to `mysite.com/ABC123abc`

I've tried this code but probably is wrong:

```
$request = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$path = $request["path"];
$_GET['id'] = $path; //my server returns error 404 - not found
```

Googled it about and haven't found anything, sorry if is duplicated question.

Comment: you can use htaccess file for that

Comment: Any example about how?

Comment: this not the exact one but will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28168375/how-to-write-htaccess-rewrite-rule-for-seo-friendly-url

Comment: pass: mysite.com/?id=123 to mysite.com/123 ? confusing, can you make it clearer?

Comment: My index php file uses `$_GET['id']` to get id values, I want it to be recognized as pages format, `mysite.com/123` not `/?id=123`, got it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your site,you can use the `.htaccess` file (he is used to make commands to Apache) on the folder of your project, inside him, put the code to Rewrite your URL:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

The RewriteEngine is a mechanism where each write of the url, the request is rewritten otherwise, which you specify.

On documentation of [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) you can look more of the RewriteEngine.

Comment: There's only a problem, my id queries are like these: A12ABC1234567

Comment: use ([0-9a-zA-Z]+) rather than ([0-9]+)

Comment: Ok, I'll give a try.

Comment: I've created a numeric id query `5` for testing, still returning error 404.

Comment: you have create a htaccess as above section ?? and your main page name is index.php wether you try to get id ??

Comment: edit the code according with your necessity, The error can be due to the ´/´ after the ´+)´

Comment: @LucasVianaSantos Thanks for the support. I removed first slash in RewriteRule `^/` and it is working well. '-'

Comment: Good know it, I hope I've helped you. I will edit the code

Answer (score 0):

you can done this things using `htaccess`

Create SEO Friendly URLs With Htaccess Mod Rewrite

Example : http://parthmy007.in/user/123

Now you want to access `123`n as parameter using `id`
so for this you have to wright htaccess file

1. Creating .htaccess file

Open NotePad (yes, the windows notepad) > File > Save As > Change the “Save as Type” to “All Files” > enter “.htaccess” as the name and press Save. You’ve created a htacces file.

2. Create your own rewrite rule

   RewriteEngine On

   RewriteRule ^user/([0-9]+) user.php?id=$1 [NC, L]

Comment: for more information follow this links http://sforsuresh.in/url-rewriting-using-htaccess-modrewrite/

Comment: I'm using a custom query string, numbers and letters. I use my `index.php` for the querying.

Comment: Thanks for the support, pal!