# Should I use dynamic pages or actual files for blog?

Tags: adsense, dynamic-pages

I've seen news sites (CNN, Fox News, etc.) use HTML files as their post content. For my blog, I currently use dynamic pages (e.g. www.example.com/post/?id=3).

I'm wondering if this is the correct way to go, mostly because AdSense won't accept  /post/ for ads. Is this because it's just pulling up /post/ & not the id?

So basically, which way do you recommend? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the contend of your page. But basically the good way is to create easy to read links like:

http://example.com/drive-to-norway

It's because it's easy to read for people and before clicking the user knowns what it could be (instead for example: http://example.com/id=3)

Some bigger pages do not use that convention because they for example sell a lot of similar items and having named, unique links without any numbering isn't possible/easy for them. Like I wrote at the beginning - it depends on content.

Comment: So yes? Should I use a dedicated folder for each post? I'm kind of worried about storage. Also, each page has to be approved for Adsense, so if I post something new, it'll take another week to get my page approved.

Comment: Please let me know which CMS you are using, I will suggest you best solution.

Comment: @Mohit Custom. Made it myself in PHP. It has the options of most CMSs though, and if it doesn't, it shouldn't be too hard to add.

Comment: @DogeDude it is not hard to make url's SEO friendly in PHP, you can still do it using htaccess rules(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28168375/how-to-write-htaccess-rewrite-rule-for-seo-friendly-url), however it is quite hard to do it in custom code but achievable though. I suggest you should use any built in framework of PHP which allows SEO friendly url's and CRUD operations too.

Comment: @Mohit Thanks for the input

Comment: @DogeDude my pleasure sir