# How to rename the url of each page in the address bar?

Tags: html, .htaccess, url

Hello guys let me try to explain what I'm trying to do.
My web site www.website.com has a few pages and it is hosted Apache via Aruba

```
www.website.com/site/index.php
               /site/page1.php
               /site/page2.php
               /site/page2.php?action=someaction=12345
```

My question for you is, can I rename them in a simple way like

```
www.website.com/site/index.php ---> www.website.com
               /site/page1.php ---> www.website.com/page1
               /site/page2.php ---> www.website.com/page2
               /site/page2.php?action=someaction=12345 ---> www.website.com/page2
```

I've read online about .htaccess but I have no clue how to set it up, can someone explain it to me?
Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write htaccess rewrite rule for seo friendly url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28168375/how-to-write-htaccess-rewrite-rule-for-seo-friendly-url)

Answer (score 0):

I think it`s like this:

```
  RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^website.com/site/index ?$ website.com
    RewriteRule ^website.com/page([0-9]+)/ website.com/site/page=$1
    RewriteRule ^website.com/site/page([0-9]+) /?action=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Comment: I appreciate the help but can you explain it to me why is that the way it is?
Can I manage the various action that occur in a page in a general way? like:
RewriteRule ^website.com/site/page2?action={any function}={anyvalue} ?$ website.com/page2