# I want to redirect an SEO friendly URL to a non-SEO friendly but keep the URL SEO friendly

Tags: php, .htaccess

I hope you can help me.  I'm trying to create a URL rewrite, redirect, or combination of the two in a .htaccess file, but I don't know how.  It's kinda hard to find anything definitive on URL rewrites.

Basically, I want the user to be able to type in a SEO friendly URL (just one level) and have that sent to a page where I can do a $_GET['data'] and do a mysql query and serve up a web page.  I don't want the URL the user sees to change though so I'm not sure if I need to redirect it back to the SEO friendly or if it can just stay the same SEO friendly version.

Here's my example:

The user would type in this URL:
**[www.mysite.com/cars](http://www.mysite.com/cars)**

somehow, that would be either redirected or rewritten as:
**[www.mysite.com/getpage.php?page=cars](http://www.mysite.com/getpage.php?page=cars)**

but the URL stays the same:
**[www.mysite.com/cars](http://www.mysite.com/cars)**

I'm pretty sure this is a URL rewrite or redirect or a combination of the two but I have no idea how to write the rewrite rules.  I

Any assistance you can offer would be extremely helpful!

Thanks
Keyogee

Comment: What you're after is called a rewrite, ie the URL is re-written (internally) to one your app can make sense of. There are a lot of examples of this online so what have you found and tried out?

Comment: Here's a very basic example ~ https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=04f88f24-4f69-4765-93aa-d849ffbea86c

Comment: From the duplicate, I like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28169287/283366) the best

Comment: Phil, thanks SOOO much for the example you shared.  That's EXACTLY what I needed.