# PHP - get URL param with or without key

Tags: php, url

I know how to do this in a clunky verbose way, but is there an elegant way to retrieve a single param from a URL whether or not there is a key or index page in the URL? i.e. there will never be a `&secondparam=blah`.

`$_GET["slug"]` only works if the url has `slug=foobar`

E.g. return `foobar` for any of these URLs

```
site.com/page/index.php?slug=foobar

site.com/page/index.php?foobar

site.com/page/?slug=foobar

site.com/page/?foobar
```

Comment: your URLs are so varied how can you be sure there will never be a second param? you should conform to `site.com/page/foobar`, then you can be sure the controller is page and the action is foobar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

function reader()
{
    foreach($_GET as $key => $val)
    {
        if( ! empty($val))
        {
            return $val;
        }
        return $key;
    }
}

echo reader();
?>
```

Explaination:
return $value first. If not empty, return that $key

Comment: Thank you kindly, that totally works. Do you have a tip / article link for implementing a vanilla PHP MVC where I can replace `site.com/venues/?venue=venue-name` with `site.com/venues/venue-name` and not have to create directories with index pages in each?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28168375/how-to-write-htaccess-rewrite-rule-for-seo-friendly-url

Answer (score 2):

Here's my solution:

```php
$slug = $_GET['slug'] ?? reset(array_keys($_GET));

var_dump($slug);
```

It will return the first parameter name when `slug` is not found.

Be aware that it will be an empty string when the URL parameter 'slug' has no value, i.e.: `?slug` and `false` if no parameter is found at all.

Perhaps this is a little more consistent:

```php
// edit: added redundant parentheses to make operator precedence more clear
$slug = ($_GET['slug'] ?? reset(array_keys($_GET))) ?: null;

var_dump($slug);
```

...as it will return `null` for both previously mentioned edge cases.

Answer (score 1):

$_GET is actually an array that holds all of that information.

Just use an if statement

```
if(empty($_GET)) {
    continue
}
```